# Custom Labels for Address Fields Craft Commerce

Tags: form, ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce, label, shipping

I need to be able to assign and output my own custom labels for the fields that are in the shipping/billing addresses during checkout in Craft Commerce.

I've already done so on the form like so:

```
{% set countries = craft.commerce.countriesList %}
{% set states = craft.commerce.statesArray %}
{% set addressFields = {
    firstName: {
        label: 'First Name',
        required: 1,
    },
    lastName: {
        label: 'Last Name',
        required: 1,
    },
    address1: {
        label: 'Address',
        required: 1,
    },
    address2: {
        label: 'Address 2',
        required: 1,
    },
    city: {
        label: 'City',
        required: 1,
    },
    zipCode: {
        label: 'Zip Code',
        required: 1,
    },
    phone: {
        label: 'Phone',
        required: 1,
    },
    alternativePhone: {
        label: 'Alternative Phone',
        required: 1,
    },
} %}


{% set modelName = modelName is defined ? modelName : 'address' %}
{% set model = address is defined ? address : null %}

<div class="addressBox {{ modelName }}">
    {% for key,options in addressFields %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 {% if model and model.getErrors(key) %}has-error{% endif %}">
            <label for="{{ modelName }}-{{ key }}">{{ options.label|t }}{{ options.required ? '*' : '' }}</label>
            <input type="text" id="{{ modelName }}-{{ key }}" class="u-full-width" name="{{ modelName }}[{{ key }}]"
                   value="{{ model ? model[key] : '' }}">
            {% if model and model.getErrors(key) %}
                <span class="flash alert-warning">{{ model.getErrors(key)|join }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

That works like a charm. I need to however also be able to output it with my custom labels as well. Here is my currently template area, i'm not sure how i can get my custom labels in here. Please advise:

```
{% for address in addresses %}
     {% for key,value in address.attributes() %}

          {% switch key %}

               {% case "id" %} {# ingore #}
               {% case "customerId" %} {# ingore #}

               {% default %}

               {% if value %}
                    <li>
                         <h3 class="cart-product-details">{{ key|title }}:
                              <span class="address-option" data-key="{{ key }}" data-value="{{ value }}">
                                   {{ key == 'countryId' ? address.countryText : (key == 'stateId' ? address.stateText : value) }}
                              </span>
                        </h3>
                    </li>
               {% endif %}

          {% endswitch %}

     {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the attribute function:

```
{% set field = attribute(addressFields, key) %}
{{ field.label }}
```